# Specifying through dependency in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails, ruby-datamapper

I would like to express through relationship with FactoryGirl. I have three models A, B and BA where model A is independent, model of B is as follows:

```
Class B 
   include DataMapper::Resource
   property :prop1
   property :prop2
   ...
   has n, :propn, :through => :ba
end
```

And model of A is as follows:

```
 Class A 
   include DataMapper::Resource
   property :propn
 end
```

And model of BA is as follows:

```
Class BA 
   include DataMapper::Resource 
   belong_to :a, :key=>true
   belong_to :b, :key=>true
end
```

In my spec file I am creating model of A and B as follows:

```
@a = FactoryGirl.create(:a)
@b = FactoryGirl.create(:b)
```

Because of this model BA, B cannot be created, it is giving errors. Actually I don't know how to specify the dependency on A through BA which is required. In other words I cannot write the following part which I have clearly specified below.

```
 factory :c do
   association :a
   association :b
 end

 factory :b do |x|
   x.prop1    <val1>
   x.prop2    <val2>
    ...
   <to be filled to write depency on b through ba>
 end
```

So please help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the format `class Foo do ... `.  Did you mean to include the `do`?  If so, can you point me to some documentation?

Comment: Sorry do will not come.

Answer (score 1):

You can use after(:create) to set an association in factory girl. I replaced some of my model names with a and b to try to match it to your example. Also, when you are just setting attributes you don't need |x|.

```
factory :a_with_b, class: a do
    quantity_needed           2
    description               "cold"
    event_id 1
    guest_created             false
    after(:create) do |a|
        b = FactoryGirl.build(:b)
        a.ab << b
    end
end
```